# Rails RSpec Sucker Punch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

Please forgive the Rails, RSpec newbie question here.

I'm trying to use RSpec to test methods inside a class I've created in the file `app/workers/myworker.rb`. Something like this:

```
class MyWorker
   include SuckerPunch::Worker

   def perform(user_id)
     do_stuff(user_id)
     #etc
   end

   def do_stuff(user_id)
     # do stuff
   end
end
```

I have a spec file `spec/workers/myworker_spec.rb`, something like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MyWorker do
  describe "do_stuff method" do
    test = do_stuff(3)
  end
end
```

I'm getting `undefined method 'do_stuff' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007fef211b7840>`

Any tips on how to include this `MyWorker` class and its methods so that I can test them with RSpec?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you've given, there's no `require` or `require_relative` of the `app/workers/myworker.rb`, and the "test" isn't in an [example group](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-13/docs/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it!).

Until those things are in there any other problems you may be having are moot.

---

With the style you've used above, you get an *implicit* subject:

```
describe MyWorker do
  # subject { MyWorker.new } # this is not needed, and is kept in `subject`
  describe "do_stuff method" do
    it { should do_stuff(3) }  # but `subject` doesn't need to be used when it's implicit.
  end
end
```

However, that still doesn't look like a real spec, it should probably be more like this:

```
describe MyWorker do
  let(:worker){ MyWorker.new }
  describe "do_stuff method" do
    subject { worker.do_stuff(3)}
    it { should_not be_nil }
    its(:total) { should == 12 }
  end
end
```

Something like that. See [this in the docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/subject/implicit-subject) and [this blog post](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/). You still need to put the test in an example group. When you do, you'll get the `subject` (i.e. `worker` in your answer) for free.

Comment: turns out this was not the issue. i think `describe MyWorker do` makes the `MyWorker` class available? in any case, the issue was that i was not instantiating the class, e.g., `worker = MyWorker.new`, then `worker.do_stuff(3)`.

Comment: @seanomlor It makes it available, if it's already been defined, which is what the `require` is for. It's quite possible rails-rspec has already loaded it for you. Glad you got it fixed, though I've updated the answer with some possibly helpful thoughts.

Comment: thanks. i think your update makes this worthy of being the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Wow. The answer was silly obvious.

I had been assuming that `app/workers/myworker.rb` needed to be required somehow, but the real issue was simply that I was not instantiating my class.

```
describe MyWorker do
  describe "do_stuff method" do
    worker = MyWorker.new
    test = worker.do_stuff(3)
  end
end
```

This works.

Comment: Great to see you solved it! Accept an answer and get this post ticked off :)

Answer (score 0):

You mis `do`, at the `describe MyWorker` string:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MyWorker do
  describe "do_stuff method" do
    test = do_stuff(3)
  end
end
```